DDD, How to update a ValueObject?
The question refers to a situation in which I have to update a valueobject.
For example, I have a Product valueobject with a List<String> tags property in it. For some reason, I have to update this tag list after I create the valueobject, for example, add a new tag in it.
But a valueobject is supposed to be immutable, and I can't turn this Product to an Entity because I don't have any identifier to make it unique.
In another words, is a valueobject can't change at all? Then why not we just make every field "Final" and every collection unmodifiable?


How to update a ValueObject?

In the common case, you don't.
Part of the point of value objects is that they are analogous to values, like 7.
7 is a thing that doesn't change; for example
x = 7
y = x
y += 1

We haven't changed 7 - the value held by x is the same as it always was; what we have changed is that y has replaced its reference to a 7 to be a reference to an 8.
6 < 7

This boolean expression evaluates true, and because 6 and 7 are values, there's nothing you can do in your program that would change that.
Also, notice that we really don't care which 7 we are talking about...
x = 7
y = 7
y += 1

The fact that y is initialized using a "different" 7 doesn't change the semantics of the program in any way.
Value objects are "just" a design pattern that gives us objects that have similar properties to 7.

correctness of a program doesn't depend on whether references to value objects point to the same location in memory / on the stack; we only care that they are "equivalent".
the meaning of the value object doesn't change during the execution of the program (i.e. the value object is an "immutable" abstraction)


Value Objects typically appear for two reasons

We're working in a general purpose language that doesn't have the semantics we need built into it.  For example, if your domain needs int, or IEEE-754 float, then it's likely your programming language already has something that works.  But if your domain needs colors of the rainbow, then you are probably going to need something bespoke.

In languages with built in type checking, it can be useful to design value objects as a mechanism to remove ambiguity about the semantics of a value, so that the machine can alert you to the fact that you've passed a Money to code that is expecting an OrderItemQuantity

Value Objects give you a logical place in your design to put the methods that act on the underlying data structure - functions associated with Money go in the Money value object, functions associated with rainbow colors go to the RainbowColor object, and so on.




I have a Product valueobject with a List tags property in it. For some reason, I have to update this tag list after I create the valueobject, for example, add a new tag in it.

Assuming that you are correct in your analysis that Product should be a value, the usual answer is that you create a new Product when you change the tags:
class Product {
  // ...
  Product addTag(String tag) {
     List<String> updatedTags = copy(this.tags)
     updatedTags.add(tag);
     return new Product(
        this.sku,
        updatedTags
     );
  }
}

Essentially, we are implementing "copy on write" - or "FauxO" as described by Gary Bernhardt


In another words, is a valueobject can't change at all? Then why not we just make every field "Final" and every collection unmodifiable?

In the common case, yes! and making that explicit in your code definitions can make a lot of sense.
(Note: depending on the language semantics available, collections can be tricky, as immutable collections of mutable objects may not have the guarantees that you want).

My use of "common case" in the above is a bit of a hedge; it's all true, as far as it goes, and maintaining your code will be a lot easier if you can arrange things so that it is true in your case, but....
Chapter 5 of Domain Driven Design: Tackling Complexity at the Heart of Software (the original DDD book by Eric Evans) includes a side bar titled: When to Allow Mutability.

There are cases where performance considerations will favor allowing a VALUE OBJECT to be mutable....  If a VALUE's implementation is to be mutable, then it must not be shared.

I'm not too fond of this position; my preference would be that we restrict VALUE OBJECT to the immutable case, and if necessary invent some new pattern name to describe cases where we use mutable data structures in our computation.
